# php while $count, want to add all the result

Tags: php

Im facing some issue on counting total number of output.

```
<?php
$count = 1;
while ($count <= 10)
{
echo "$count ";
++$count;
}
?>
```

**Result output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

so what i want is to add all the result that is

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = ?  in my same code?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$count = 1;
$add=0;
while ($count <= 10)
{
$add=$add+$count;
echo "$count ";
++$count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 1;
$countall = 0;
while ($count <= 10)
{

echo "$count ";
$countall=$countall+$count;
$count++;
}
 echo "$countall";
```

try this

Comment: this one is almost same above by @LoVeSmItH

Comment: we both submitted it at same time :P

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `range` function and `array_sum` to get the result

```
array_sum(range(1,10))
```

Comment: yes but number may not in 1 to 10 or may be it can 1,3,5,8 etc but thanks

Comment: it the step is fixed, you can use the 3rd parameter (`step`) in `range` function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 1):

Evidently not what you are looking for, but if what you need is to calculate a summation, you can use this formula:

[image]

Using it you can calculate the result of adding all the values of `$count` in this code:

```
<?php
    $count = 1;
    while ($count <= $n)
    {
        echo $count.' ';
        ++$count;
    }
?>
```

That will be:

```
<?php
    $result = $n * ($n + 1) / 2;
?>
```

Which for `$n` = 10 is 55.